# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: in the JSP page of a Spring MVC Application

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl, el

I have 2 tables in the database (airports and stopovers). 
I wrote a SQL join query get a result set that has fields from both the tables. 
In order to map the result, i created a Custom object 'VbResult'. (There is no table in the DB corresponding to this domain object)

Please find below code for Domain object, Controller and the View: 
When i invoke the home page i get the exception, though i have the field ressrc in VbResult class.

(or) Is it wrong to use a custom object as VbResult - just for the sake of View , for which no table exists?

I am stuck for a long time.. What is that I am missing here!   Please let me know!

Thanks in advance

**javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'ressrc' not found on type com.datacaliper.vbuddy.domain.VbResult**

Domain Object: VbResult

```
public class VbResult implements java.io.Serializable{  
private static final long serialVersionUID = -3606761414209638631L;  
private Integer resid;  
private String resairline;  
private String resemail;  
private String ressrc;  
private String resdes;  
//private String res_airline;     

public VbResult(){  }  

public VbResult(Integer id, String airline, String email,  
        String source, String destination) {  
    this.resid= id;  
    this.resairline = airline;  
    this.resemail = email;  
    this.ressrc = source;  
    this.resdes = destination;  
}  

public Integer getId() {  
    return this.resid;  
}  
public void setId(Integer id) {  
    this.resid = id;  
}  
public String getAirline() {  
    return this.resairline;  
}  
public void setAirline(String airline) {  
    this.resairline = airline;  
}  
public String getEmail() {  
    return this.resemail;  
}  
public void setEmail(String email) {  
    this.resemail = email;  
}  
public String getSource() {  
    return this.ressrc;  
}  
public void setSource(String source) {  
    this.ressrc = source;  
}  
public String getDestination() {  
    return this.resdes;  
}  
public void setDestination(String destination) {  
    this.resdes = destination;  
}  
}
```

**Controller Code:**

```
@Controller  
@RequestMapping({"/","/main"})  
public class MainController {  
protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("controller");  
@Resource(name="PostService")  
private PostService postService;  
@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
public String getStopovers(Model model) {  
logger.debug("Received request to show all Posts");  
// Retrieve all posts by delegating the call to PostService  
List<VbResult> stops = postService.getAll();  
// Attach persons to the Model  
model.addAttribute("stops", stops);  
return "homepage";       
}   
}
```

**JSPPage**

```
<c:forEach items="${stops}" var="stop">  
<tr>  
<td><c:out value="${stop.ressrc}" />  
</td>  
<td><c:out value="${stop.resdes}" />  
</td>  
</tr>  
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 2):

> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'ressrc' not found on type com.datacaliper.vbuddy.domain.VbResult

It's basically telling that there's no getter method with the name `getRessrc()` on the class with the full qualified name `com.datacaliper.vbuddy.domain.VbResult`.

And indeed, there's no such method. You've called it `getSource()`. Fix your JSP code accordingly.

```xml
<c:out value="${stop.source}" />
```

The new `PropertyNotFoundException` on `resdes` which you would get after fixing this should now be self-explaining enough ;)

Comment: yep! thanks for the reply. i just changed it and worked like a breeze